# Term for words indicating capability other than "adjective"

Tags: terminology

The words *edible* and *manageable* are adjectives, but is there a more specific term for such words indicating capability?

Comment: I don't think there is a more specific term. The only one I can think of is "Adjectives with -able/-ible suffix".

Comment: These are called **properties**

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there is an existing word, but why not use a short phrase? **Capability adjectives**, or **capability-indicating adjectives**.

Comment: "Capability" would inappropriately restrictive, since it wouldn't cover things like **fashionable** and **seasonable** (*normal for the season*, not *capable of being seasoned*). By any rational definition, these are the same "type" of suffix. Note that **-able** remains "productive" (we can form new coinages with it). The alternative **-ible** is no longer productive, so far as I know.